# SQL Query to display any part of the title

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a select statement so that it selects and returns records that match any part of the book's title? (For example, if you enter 'the' then it will display all titles that have the word 'the')

Comment: `LIKE` is the general solution. Some dbms products have word search too. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: If you are searching for words, then consider a full text add-on for your database.  Do note that `the` is typically a stop word and filtered out for comparisons.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this :

```
declare @searchString nvarchar(500)
set @searchString = N'book'
    
select 
       * 
from 
       books
where 
       title like '%'+@searchString+'%'
```

Comment: Will also return `mother`.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to get this right. You will not get the title `'The Titans'` now.

Comment: Word search functionality if available. Otherwise you can do `' ' || title || ' ' like '% the %'` to get a bit closer. Using a case insensitive collation to also get `The`. It's a mess. Remove all non-letter characters, like digits, commas,etc.

Comment: @Ehsan ok well, this will only display the titles with 'the'. What if I want to search for other parts of the book's title, for example like 'book'?

Comment: @eme you can do something like this : like '%the%book%' , however this is not the fastest way to do this in sql , another solution to this can be full text seatch